# Problems with pass-by-reference in Python 2d list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Take this dict of dicts:

```
case_forms = {'plural': {'nominative': 'dni', 'locative': 'dniach'}, 
              'singular': {'instrumental': 'dniem', 'vocative': 'dzie\xc5\x84'}}
```

I'd like to get a list of all the (a,b) key-pairs that are usable as `case_forms[a][b]`.

No problem, right? Double list comprehension. Do stuff like that all the time in Haskell:

```
[(number, case_name) for case_name in case_dict.keys() for number, case_dict in case_forms.items()]
```

Except this doesn't produce the result you would expect:

```
[('plural', 'instrumental'),
 ('singular', 'instrumental'),
 ('plural', 'vocative'),
 ('singular', 'vocative')]
```

I'm wondering how to fix this problem. No amount of cleverly placed `[:]` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Read the list comprehension more closely, it's defined as the second part of  the tuple when `case_forms.items()` is called.

Comment: I see that now. It however doesn't change the `NameError: name 'case_dict' is not defined`.

Comment: you must have input the code sample incorrectly. I don't experience that error.

Comment: What does this have to do with pass-by-reference, which Python does *not* have?

Comment: I've done a straight cut-and-paste in both 2.7 and 3.5; I get that case_dict isn't defined in both.

Comment: @Prune that's impossible, I've just done the exact same thing and it works on 2.7.12

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you're right, what I mean is that somehow the list comprehension is *using* a reference internally instead of making new strings.

Comment: @TomBusby Because in Python 2 list comprehensions have leaky scope, and it's not useng the `case_dict` you think it is, it's using the `case_dict` from a previous comprehension (that leaked into the external scope).

Comment: I still don't understand how you guys are getting NameError and I'm not though

Comment: Read my previous post. Start a new interpreter session and you'll get the `NameError`.

Comment: I think the downvotes are pretty unfair though tbh. This is a valid question where a piece of code is producing non-intuitive output

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you haven't provided a reproducible example, which is why you are getting downvoted. In any event, did you try starting a new session and pasting the above code? You will get a `NameError`

Comment: "Python 2 list comprehensions have leaky scope, and it's not useng the case_dict you think it is, it's using the case_dict from a previous comprehension (that leaked into the external scope)" "Start a new interpreter session and you'll get the NameError" this is the actual answer.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you everyone, and apologies for my earlier incredulity that you were getting the NameError.

Comment: @TomBusby No worries, but as an aside, you should definitely be using Python 3 if you ccan. Python 2 is at it's official end of life in 2020.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After this debacle, I might just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this :

```
[ (number, case_name) for number, case_dict in case_forms.items() for case_name in case_dict.keys() ]
```

Edited to reference @juanpa.arrivillaga's comments about why my example was behaving strangely:

> Python 2 list comprehensions have leaky scope, and it's not using the case_dict you think it is, it's using the case_dict from a previous comprehension (that leaked into the external scope)
>
> Start a new interpreter session and you'll get the NameError

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you very much. I'm still very keen to understand why my version produces incorrect output though

Comment: @TomBusby because your comprehension is in the reversed order, hence the `NameError`. The `for` expression is written in the same order you would write it if you were doing a nested for-loop

Comment: Going to edit this to quote @juanpa.arrivillaga and accept this as the correct answer